# GROUP BY, show MIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following query to get me a list of titles:

```
select 
  title, 
  date 
from 
  financials,
order by 
title, date

title                       date
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-06-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-07-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-07-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-07-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-08-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-09-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-09-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-09-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-09-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-10-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-10-01
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-10-01
11'e 10 Kala            2012-12-01
11'e 10 Kala            2012-12-01
11'e 10 Kala            2012-12-01
11'e 10 Kala            2012-12-01
11'e 10 Kala            2013-01-01
```

I need to group the titles and then get the MIN(date) of the transaction. The correct query would yield:

```
title                   date 
1,000 Times More Brutal 2013-06-01
11'e 10 Kala            2012-12-01
```

How would I use a GROUP BY query to get the min date here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT title, MIN(date)
FROM financials
GROUP BY title
ORDER BY title
```

Comment: I don't need to add a subselect here?

Comment: @David542 nope, this should do it

Comment: Check other 2 answers: no

Comment: When using group by with many columns, a nice trick is to write numbers to reference the columns instead of names.               `SELECT title, MIN(date)
FROM financials
GROUP BY 1`

Comment: @Martin It's a trick but I wouldn't recommend doing it, too easy to forget to update if you make a change the query. And it's a bad habit even if you don't change the query because having it with a select * can introduce errors if the table columns change too. It works but it's just too risky for me.

Comment: @Jean-BernardPellerin It's actually quite a normal practise. Think of grouping by 30 columns, something that is somehow common if you are dealing with many columns. Would you write 30 names? or just write 1,2,3,4,5,6.. If you have a wrong number of columns, the query won't work. There is no room for errors.

Answer (score 2):

```
select title, min(date)
from financials
group by title
order by title, date
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT title, MIN(date) 
FROM financials
GROUP BY title
```

Comment: Normally one should be honest at least to himself, are you?

Answer (score 2):

```
select title, min(date) from financials group by title order by title
```